# What is bootstrap yaml in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

> What is bootstrap yaml in spring boot?  
>   And could you advise where I can use it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately general questions about which software or APIs to use are not permitted. You might try [Software Recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). But I would advise doing more research first as these questions are too broad to be useful in my opinion.

Comment: From what i see, he's not asking whether to use Spring Boot or not, and why SB is better than other frameworks. He asked what is a bootstrap.yaml file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

bootstrap.yml is used in spring cloud 
It is starting before application.yml
It is almost use with spring cloud config server
Spring cloud config server is server which is used to externilize your application configuration. 
And when starting your application bootstrap.yml will take the configuration from spring cloud config server. 
It also can use encrypting and decrypting some information by :

```
'{cipher}someyour encoded text'
```

and server will decode it while pulling the configurations
But you need to create jks
You can reach the documentation for more information about spring cloud :

https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

Configuration files in spring  boot will be loaded in such order:

```
 1. src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml
 2. src/main/resources/application.yml
 3. config/application.yml
```